# Remove first new line and first character from nvarchar. Ms SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have nvarchar variable like this

```
DECLARE @SelectFields NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SelectFields = N'

         ,[Id]
         ,[Name]
        ,[ShortName]';
```

I want to remove only the first new line (if exist) and the "," before first colum name. I want to have this:

```
  [Id]
 ,[Name]
 ,[ShortName]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT RIGHT( @SelectFields, LEN(@SelectFields) - CHARINDEX(',', @SelectFields))`

Comment: what about my post...?

Answer (score 1):

This should basically do what you require:

```
declare @SelectFields nvarchar(max)    
set @SelectFields = N'

 ,[Id]
 ,[Name]
,[ShortName]'

-- replace any carriage returns and blank spaces
set @SelectFields = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@SelectFields, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''), ' ', '')
-- remove any leading commas
select case when left(@SelectFields, 1) = ',' 
            then substring(@SelectFields, 2, len(@SelectFields) ) 
            else @SelectFields end as Result
```

I'd question why you would want to do something like this though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do simply using `stuff()` like as,

```
DECLARE @SelectFields NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SelectFields = N'

         ,[Id]
         ,[Name]
        ,[ShortName]';

select stuff(@selectfields, 1, charindex(',', @selectfields),'')
```